Do dimmers affect consumption?
I'm almost hesitant to ask this question because it just seems like I'm going to get lambasted with the obvious but I truly do not know the answer. This is a two prong (no pun intended) question.
If I dial down (dim) a lamp using a simple wall mounted 120V dimmer switch, will that lamp consume less energy?  In other words,  would dimming my lights lower my electric bill? If so, is the same true when dimming an LED bulb?

What kind of dimmers? There are different types.

Yes, using a dimmer will typically reduce power consumption. Residential power in most places is measured as real consumption so there's no funny business with power factors. LED bulbs (if the dimmer works) or incandescent.
If you still have incandescent bulbs, you'll get less light per watt (and it will be redder), but there will still be less watts.
It's hard to imagine a situation where a dimmer would increase consumption, but there may be edge or weird cases. The dimmer itself draws a bit of power so at full power there might be a tiny loss. The old two-wire dimmers are just in series with the bulb so they will likely decrease consumption at any setting.

Most low power LED bulbs convert AC to DC and then use that to power individual LEDs. For a dimmable bulb (at least the ones that work well with out flickering on and off) an additional circuit senses the phase cut signal on the AC waveform and adjust the LED current directly. For example, without a dimmer signal a bulb may draw 50mA. When dimmed to half power the circuit will adjust the LED current to 25 mA. This directly reduces how much energy is consumed by the device.
